# AWS controlling which instance is scaled-in when autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to have a scale-in policy where nodes are scaled-in when the CPU is under 30%.

How can I control that the individual instance selected for scaling-in is the one with lowest CPU or at least a CPU under 30%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By default, Auto Scaling first identifies which Availability** Zone has the most instances (or, if they are equal, it picks a random AZ). Then, it uses the **Termination Policy** to determine which instance to [control which instance Auto Scaling terminates during scale-in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#custom-termination-policy).

However, Auto Scaling does not select an instance based upon how 'busy' that particular is -- after all, that instance might be more busy, or less busy, a few seconds later.

Fortunately, Auto Scaling uses [connection draining](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html) to allow **in-flight requests** to complete before the instance is terminated. Therefore, in theory, it doesn't matter that the instance is temporarily busy.

If you have long-running tasks on an instance that you don't want interrupted, you can configure [Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to move instances into a `Terminating:Wait` state. The instances will not receive any new traffic. Your application can then **signal when the long-running task has completed** (eg copying log files to S3, or finishing video rendering) and Auto Scaling will then terminate the instance.

Finally, if you want more **fine-grained control** over which instance will be terminated, you (or your application) can specifically [Detach EC2 Instances From Your Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html) via the management console or a `describe-auto-scaling-instances` API call.